# Manually calculating marginal effects

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, logit

Let's say I have the following regression specification:

```
model <- glm(income ~ education + age + married + race + left + quartile_health, family=binomial, data=data)
```

--If I wanted to compute the marginal effect of left (a binary variable taking 1 if individual is left-handed), holding other co-variates at their mean. How would I do this?  I get that I can compute this with R-libraries like so:

```
logitmfx(income ~ education + age + married + race + left + quartile_health, data = data,  atmean = TRUE)
```

But I'd ilke to compute this manually.

--I want to predict the value of being left-handed, holding other co-variates at their mean.  My general strategy for this is to grab the coefficients from the model, multiply them by their respective means, and get a prediction like so:

```
coef(r_3)[1] + coef(r_3)[2]*mean_income + coef(r_3)[3]*mean_age + coef(r_3)*mean_married[4] + coef(r_3)[5]*mean_race + coef(r_3)[6] + coef(r_3)[7]*meanhealth
```

The issue is that quartile_health doesn't have a mean, as it's a factor variable dividing the data into four quartiles (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4) based upon their health. So how do I make predictions at the mean with this co-variate present?